# Forwarding data on a port to another external server retaining source IP

Tags: linux

I have 2 linux servers, Server A with IP 1.1.1.1 and Server B with IP 2.2.2.2 in 2 different geographical locations. I want all the data arriving on a specific TCP port (5678) on Server B to be forwarded to Server A.

I have tried using rinetd for forwarding the data from Server B to Server A. It works fine, however the Source IP received at Server A is changing to the IP address of Server B. I want Server B to act as a simple transparent relay and the Source IP to be the same as the originating client IP.

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: @RonMaupin Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @RonMaupin Unfortunately, Server B is a rented server and we don't have access to the network router. The primary reason for renting Server B is to act as a relay, so processing overhead is totally acceptable.

Comment: I would say that if you can't use the network infrastructure, only the server, you are probably better off asking on Server Fault. Network Engineering can't help you if you have no control over the network.

Comment: NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. This question seems to be more related to server/computer configuration which is off topic as defined by the community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [sf]. Unfortunately, this is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

Iptables, which is a utility for configuration of netfilter firewall would do.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -X

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5678 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:5678
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 2.2.2.2 --dport 5678 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.1
```

Iptables is very powerful tool so getting accustomed with it is a must (http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables or just google some tutorials)

But if you a proxying HTTP protocol - using nginx (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) will be much easier

Comment: The connection forwarding works fine with these rules, however on Server A, the source IP of the connection is Server B instead of the real originating client IP. I don't intend to use this forwarding for HTTP.